# inserting and retrieving python dataframe in hana database

Tags: python, dataframe, sqlalchemy, hana, sap-cloud-platform

I have a python dataframe that I want to insert directly into HANA database and also wants to read it from database.

I have tried this code :

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('hana+pyhdb://username:password@example.com:port')
my_df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]], columns=["A", "B"])
my_df.to_sql('table_name', con = engine, index = False, if_exists = 'replace')
```

**Error: DBAPIError: (hdbcli.dbapi.Error) (4321, 'only secure connections are allowed') (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/dbapi)***

**Is this about adding ssl certificate? How to add it in the engine ?**

However, I'm able to connect OK via the Python API using the encrypt option:

```
conn = dbapi.connect(
    address="host",
    port=portnr,
    encrypt="true",
    user="user",
    password="pwd"
)
```

But, if I pass this connection object here:

```
my_df.to_sql('table_name', con = conn, index = False, if_exists = 'replace')
```

I'll still get an error. How to fix this?

Comment: What error do you get when you run the `to_sql` method?

Comment: I've written it in the question.. This one ->  DBAPIError: (hdbcli.dbapi.Error) (4321, 'only secure connections are allowed') (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/dbapi)*

Answer (score 0):

The HANA DB you are using has secure connections enabled.
So you need to pass encrypt=true in your connection URL. If the certificate is self signed, you many need to ignore that by adding sslvalidatecertificate=false

Try following:

```
connection_string = 'hana://%s:%s@%s:%s/?encrypt=true&sslvalidatecertificate=false' % (hdb_user, hdb_password, hdb_host, hdb_port)
engine = create_engine(connection_string)
```